# Wired Go-Redis transaction behavior

Tags: go, redis, transactions, go-redis

I'm learning Redis and trying to use Redis (cluster-mode) transaction wrap up several operations.
The library I use is go-redis v9.5.1.
The code two wrap four commands in a transaction, then return the current server time for another command insert into a sorted set.

```
ctx := context.Background()
pipe := s.c.TxPipeline()

// New token is added to the tail of the queue
pipe.Incr(ctx, s.tailKey(Id, Key))
pipe.Get(ctx, s.headKey(Id, Key))
pipe.Get(ctx, s.resetKey(Id, Key))
pipe.Time(ctx)

cmds, err := pipe.Exec(ctx)
if err != nil && !errors.Is(err, redis.Nil) {
    log.Error().Err(err).Msg("redis")
    return 0, 0, nil, err
}
```

However, when I run MONITOR command to debug on Redis, it print out the following commands:

```
1710299128.368998 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "multi"
1710299128.369037 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "incr" "{KEY}:tp"
1710299128.369046 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "get" "{KEY}:hp"
1710299128.369050 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "get" "{KEY}:rs"
1710299128.369054 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "exec"
1710299128.369800 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "multi"
1710299128.369810 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "time"
1710299128.369812 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "exec"
```

It seems like the lib break my transaction into two multi-exec command blocks. To cross-check I debugged other part of my code. I also found another similar situation that one transaction translated into two multi-exec block.

```
_, err = s.c.TxPipelined(ctx, func(p redis.Pipeliner) error {
    p.ZAddNX(ctx, s.queueKey(TEST, KEY), redis.Z{Member:t.ID, Score: timeToRedisScore(t.CreatedTime)})
    p.HSet(ctx, s.sessionKey(TEST, KEY, t.ID), t.ToHash())
    p.Expire(ctx, s.sessionKey(TEST, KEY, t.ID), s.TTL)
    return nil
})
```

translated to

```
1710299128.370271 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "multi"
1710299128.370297 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "zadd" "KEY:q" "nx" "1710299128369" "c5c86e7d-ed3d-4e90-86da-18a4a15f4e1c"
1710299128.370307 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "exec"

1710299128.370948 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "multi"
1710299128.370979 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "hset" "KEY:{c5c86e7d-ed3d-4e90-86da-18a4a15f4e1c}:sess" "GID" "TEST" "GRD" "LOGIN_QUEUE" "T" "c5c86e7d-ed3d-4e90-86da-18a4a15f4e1c" "1710299128369"
1710299128.371000 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "expire" "KEY:{c5c86e7d-ed3d-4e90-86da-18a4a15f4e1c}:sess" "60"
1710299128.371008 [0 192.168.73.113:58490] "exec"
```

The only similarity between those two cases I can think of is the one put into one multi-exec block shared the same hash tag ({KEY} in first case and {c5c86e7d-ed3d-4e90-86da-18a4a15f4e1c} in second case).
I tried to check the client implementation but didn't find any specific process for hash tag (maybe I'm dumb and missed it...). Does anyone saw similar issue before? 
Also, what keyslot does the TIME command hash to? It doesn't seems contains a key...XD
Any advice and help would be appreciated, thanks:-).

Comment: Of the top of my head: In both cases you operate on entirely different keys slots, within your (logical) transaction. As far as of admittedly limited understanding of Redis Cluster, when operations are affecting  different key slots, you observe expected behavior: your logical transaction gets split into two (transacted) operations. However, again as per my limited understanding, the only guarantee you have is that the operations are applied in consecutive order. Atomicity is only guaranteed for ops on the same key slot.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg. Yes agree with it. Cross-shard(key slots) transaction is very slow and go against the design of Redis. I'm wondering why TIME command is split as well. Also trying to find a way to debug how Redis explained the command send to server, like EXPLAIN in SQL based database. Would rather it throw some cross-shard exceptions than silently break my transactions into two :-)

Comment: Let me play Captain Obvious: You *really* should know your data model. If you depend on something that is considered bad practice, there might be something wrong with either your data model or the choice of database might be wrong.